# How can I enter a new type of grocery without the program closing?

Tags: java

I am making a grocery shopping program in Java. I want to be able to enter another type of grocery, but when I enter another one, the program closes how can I fix this? Also how can I make an array of the SAME random types of grocery at the end of the program?

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
// REMEMBER YOUR UPPER/LOWER CASES!

public class ShoppingGame {

public static void main (String [] args) {
    boolean done = false;
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Grocery shopping game! Enter a type of grocery: fruits, vegetables, grains" +
            " or junk foods.");
    //String [] groceries   = {"fruits", "vegetables", "wheat and grains"};
    String[] fruits = {"apples", "oranges", "bananas", "grapes"};
    String[] vegetables = {"broccoli", "green beans", "carrots", "cabbage"};
    String[] grains = {"spaghetti", "rice", "mac and cheese", "whole wheat bread"};
    String[] junkFoods = {"ice cream", "chips", "cookies", "cakes and pies"};

    Random generator = new Random();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userInput = scanner.nextLine();

    while (!done) {

        if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("fruits")) {
            int randomFruit = generator.nextInt(fruits.length);
            System.out.println(fruits[randomFruit]);
            System.out.println("Enter another one!");
            scanner.nextLine();
            done = false;
        }
        if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("vegetables")) {
            int randomVegetable = generator.nextInt(fruits.length);
            System.out.println(vegetables[randomVegetable]);
            System.out.println("Enter another one!");
            scanner.nextLine();
        }
        if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("grains")) {
            int randomGrains = generator.nextInt(fruits.length);
            System.out.println(grains[randomGrains]);
            System.out.println("Enter another one!");
            scanner.nextLine();
        }
        if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("junk foods")) {
            int randomJunkFood = generator.nextInt(fruits.length);
            System.out.println(junkFoods[randomJunkFood]);
            System.out.println("Enter another one!");
            scanner.nextLine();
        }
        if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
            done = true;
            scanner.close();
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Try again!");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `userInput = scanner.nextLine()`?

Comment: Why are you closing the scanner?

Comment: Make sure you call the userInput = scanner.next(); in the while loop to continuously read from the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe call 
String userInput = scanner.nextline(); inside the while so you dont have to call it with every if statement. And use continue; with each if statement to restart the loop.

One more thing that your if-else statement formation is wrong . Maybe put all the nested ifs in one if statement and then use else